# Gray Overlay on a custom UIButton getting displayed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, uiimage

I have created a *custom UIButton* for an *iOS 4.3+ application*. I wanted to make the background image stretch, so I  and used the following methods to set its background image:

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:myImagePath]  stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:leftStretchValue topCapHeight:topStretchValue] forState:UIControlStateNormal]
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:myHighlightedImagePath]  stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:eftStretchValue topCapHeight:topStretchValue] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:mySelectedImagePath]
stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:eftStretchValue topCapHeight:topStretchValue] forState:UIControlStateSelected]
```

I have added an event handler to the custom button

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonHighlighted:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In the above mentioned methods, I have set the selected and the highlighted state of the button accordingly. I have changed the frame of the UIButton to adjust the dimensions of an irregular image *(mySelectedImage and myHighlightedImage, neither of which is a rectangle)*, so that it gets aligned properly along with myImage.

```
- (void) buttonSelected {
myButton.selected = !myButton.selected; //setting the selected property to NO in the     viewDidLoad

//code to change the frame of the UIButton to accomodate the irregular image
}


- (void) buttonHighlighted {
myButton.highlighted = YES;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when I select myButton, *a gray color overlay* is displayed on myImage for a very short time before the images myHighlightedImage and mySelectedImage are displayed as its background. I have set the *background color of myButton as clearColor*, thinking that might be the reason, but it is not getting solved.

What could be the possible issue... ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

I think that is what you are looking for..